# GIT newbie: git fetch does not yet pull data to local?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

The remote repository has two branches: **master**, **develop**.

Then, I checked my local branch by `git branch` , I notice I have only **master** branch, so I run command `git fetch origin`.

After this, when I run "`git branch`" again, I still see only **master** branch, why, isn't "`git branch`" supposed to list all **local** branches?

Does it mean the `git fetch origin` does not yet make the **develop** as my local branch? Then what `git fetch` actually doing?

(But I can see **develop** branch with `git branch -r`)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you run `git fetch origin`, git just updates all the so-called "remote-tracking branches" - those are the ones that look like `origin/develop` and `origin/master` that you can see in the output of `git branch -r`.  You can't work directly on those branches, although in many other respects you can use them like your local branches.  If you want to work on the develop branch, you have to create a local branch based on `origin/develop`.  Using all of git's helpful "Do What I Mean" shortcuts, you can usually do this with just:

```
git checkout develop
```

... although the more explicit version of that command would be:

```
git checkout --track -b develop origin/develop
```

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` only fetches the git objects. Nothing more.

In your case, you have to create a local branch and set it to track a remote branch.